# How to get alphabet+numbers+underscore string between . and (

Tags: php, regex

I need to get any string between the characters '`.`' and '`(`' - without quotes - but the string shouldn't contain characters other than (aA to zZ), numbers (0-9) and underscore.

I am able to get anything between . and ( as below:

```
$result = preg_match('/\.(.*?)\(/', $str, $matches);
```

But unable to filter the matched strings to get just alphabet with numbers and underscore.

Sample string:

```
$str = "class._filter9({opacity:0.5, color:'red'});";
```

I need to get `_filter9`

Would you please help? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regexpal.com works wonders for testing if your regex searches work or not. Here you are sir:

```
$result = preg_match('/\.([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\(/', $str, $matches);
```

Comment: You could simplify to `'/\.(\\w+)\(/'`.

Comment: @DavidKnipe: Yes, but you don't need to double escape the `\w`

Comment: @Casimir You're probably right. But I'm more confident that it works with `\\w`. And it's arguably good practice to use `\\ ` when escaping at the regex level instead of the string literal level, since I _think_ that `/\b/` and `/\\b/` are different things.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works as a charm. Would you please suggest me any good website to read about reg exp in PHP? I am very weak with them. Cheers!